# Socket.io connection breaks on "socket.emit()" in some cases

Tags: node.js, sockets, encoding, vue.js, socket.io

I am building an app with node.js as server and vue.js in frontend with this package https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io

I am sending a lot of data from the server to the client (inital on connection)
Node.js loads the data from mongodb.

So in some cases, when I do a

> socket.emit()

the connection breaks up (with no error) and does instantly a reconnect. And this in an infinit loop.

I found out, that the problem was once caused by german "Umlauts", for example "ä, ö, ü", etc. I fixed this issue by doing this  `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myDataToSend)))` and in the frontend decode it like this: `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(payload))`

So now this doesnt help anymore and I cant figure out why. And there is no kind of error log or something where I can start debugging, it just breaks up and reconnects forever.

Can this happen because my Object I want to send to the client is **too big**?
I tried sending my data in smaller packages one after another and this did not break. I hoped I would find the problem like this.

Any advice for debugging or ideas for packing my data is appreciated.

Comment: How big is in megabytes?

Comment: I am sending 493576 chars. But, i send another package to the client with 5066154 chars. (arount 10 times more) and this one does not cause any problems!

Comment: Are there any errors on the server? Try/catch? And сan you sample these data? And sample code, how do you send data?

Comment: @stdob-- Thank you for your input. I could solve this issue by fixing my usage of vue-socket.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue wich caused my problem.

Note: I have still no idea, why the socket connection crashed in my case, but I used the package in the "wrong way".
I did:

```
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://socketserver.com:1923', store);
```

but the kind of better way ist

```
Vue.use(VueSocketio, socketio('http://socketserver.com:1923'), store);
```

vue-socket.io uses a very old version of the socket-io.client when just using a string as connection and no actual socketio instance.

Maybe this helps someone else